# Processing Code does not work

Tags: boolean, processing, collision, rectangles

I started programming with Processing today and wrote a little programm that creates 10 random rectangles
Now I like to make them disappear when the mouse is over them, but my actual code is not working

I would apprechiate some tipps ...

`import java.awt.Rectangle;

Rectangle rect[] = new Rectangle[10];
int xpos[] = new int[10];
int ypos[] = new int[10];
int size = 25;
boolean visible[] = new boolean[10];


void setup()
  {

    size(640,480);
    frameRate(60);
    smooth();
    background(0);
    stroke(255); 
    fill(255);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textSize(200);
    text("Catch", width/2, 280);
    textSize(100);
    text("them", width/2, 380);

// 10 Random positions for the rectangles  
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
         xpos[i] =  int(random (615));
         ypos[i] =  int(random (455));
         visible[i] = true;

    }
     for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
         rect[i] = new Rectangle(xpos[i],ypos[i],size,size);

  }        
}

  void draw()
  {    
      for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {

        if (visible[i] == true){
           fill(255,0,0);
           rect(rect[i].x,rect[i].y,rect[i].width,rect[i].height);}

        else if (rect[i].contains(mouseX,mouseY)){
             visible[i] = false; }


      }}`

Answer (score 0):

Why `else if`? The way it is written, it will only check to see if the mouse is over a rect if `visible[i] == false`. They are all visible so it never gets executed.

Also to see the effect, you must call `background(0);` at the top of your draw method. Otherwise you never clear the screen to see the results.

You should also consider cleaning up your indentation and braces {} to make sure you are formatting the code in a consistent way. That would make it easier to read.

Comment: thanks a lot man ^^ i only added the background(0) line and it works perfectly